# Password management : Azure Devops - Service connection, service principal manual

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have created a Azure devops service connection using service principal manual. As per the organisation security policy, password should be updated every 90 days. In this case, how do I update the Azure devops service connection to use the recent password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the service connection, click on Edit at the top-right corner of the page.

[image]

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manage-a-service-connection) you can refer to .